# Viewing MEAN app in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, meanjs

I am trying to access a barebone MEAN stack application with Google's glcloud one click deployments. I have successfully been able to add the code for the MEAN app and can access (via ssh) and run/start app using grunt. Neither of the external links provided by gcloud is working: http://:3000 or http://

Any idea on how to access app for viewing/testing?

Comment: Neither of the external links provided by gcloud is working: http://<EXTERNAL_LINK>:3000 or http://<EXTERNAL_LINK>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by allowing the default MEAN JS port 3000 on the firewall rules in the Google Developer Console. Networking > Firewall rules. You must also allow http port for incoming traffic.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!